# MS Power Automate: Better options to create a Flow?

Tags: power-automate

While i really like the low-code approach of Power-Automate, it has some definite drawbacks.
Escpecially if you have to modify (refactor) a number of flows, the whole pointing, clicking, waiting for screen refresh gets really annoying.
Things which take seconds when doing normal coding is a matter of several minutes sometimes.

In addition, the way of adding an expression is really unpractical.
Try to use a concat() method with some dynamic values and you will know what i mean - you always have to scan from left to right.
[image: Your "coding area":]
I have now started to use a normal editor like Notepad++ to write my expression and copy it to the text field.

In case you have a bigger JSON string as variable value (an Array for example), cursor position keeps jumping back to first line as soon as you enter or remove a dynamic value, resulting in the need to double/triple check where your cursor is positioned.

So for more complex flows or larger formulars, the currently available editor looks like a prototype with much room for improvement (aka is a pain "a la derriere").

Does anyone know a better way to create Power Automate Flows?
Like a VS-Code plugin with an option to directly edit the code?

Answer (score 0):

After some further research it has turned out this is a design decision by Microsoft.
I discussed the topic with some Microsoft persons and they explained to me it is the approach to be as "almost-no-code" as possible when using Power-Automate. This a valid point - on the other hand, this can get annoying by being over-simplistic.
All citizen developers i know of (and an interest in Power-Automate) have a background of being Shadow-IT Excel-VBA coders, so i would say you can expect some experience most of the time and an *option* to use code would be nice.

However, for people with a developer background and the desire to enjoy the virtues of an IDE, source code management and all other well known methodologies, there is an option called Azure Logic Apps. You could call it a Low-Code approach for developers, looking very similar to Power-Automate but offering the things you miss quickly when workin with the latter.

[Here is a formidable article by Jim Arnold explaining the differences](https://covenanttechnologypartners.com/2022/03/28/azure-logic-apps-or-power-automate/)